# Configuration options for relational algebra evaluator "ra.jar"

Tags: sqlite

I am participating in the [Stanford Database Class](https://class2go.stanford.edu/db/Winter2013/pages/overview), and there are some problem sets to be solved in "mathy" relational algebra syntax.

The course instructors demand from students to use this [open-source, free](https://github.com/junyang/RA/tree/master/src/ra) jar file "[ra.jar](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~junyang/ra/)"  to submit solutions via web forms.

```
RA: an interactive relational algebra interpreter
Version 2.1b by Jun Yang (junyang@cs.duke.edu)
>
```

I wonder if there is a better evaluator available? This one is pretty good but

- on the command-line-interpreter prompt, the cursor position is hard
  to see
- the tool translates relational alegbra experssions to SQL and submits
  them to SQLite. It does not show (return to the user) the
  intermediate steps.  There should be a -log or verbose option to
  return the SQL generated. (The ra tool has a -v option to return the submitted ra query).

I want the CREATE VIEW.... and SELECT ... SQL statements that the jar file generates and sends to SQLite. Alternatively, can I configure SQLite to echo/log all sql commands submitted to it? Is there an option for the .properties file?

Comment: Why do you need the SQL? You can use the SQLite command line tool to look at any data stored in the generated datafile. I do hope you're not somehow trying to cheat the course :)

Comment: I don't really "need" it, I just want to now what is generated (are "exists" or "in" clauses used, or how a set difference is realized etc) I know what's inside the datafile. And someone else helped a bit by putting the solutions on [github](https://github.com/yangchenyun/relational_algebra_exercise). And I know how I can add a logger object to the java code, but maybe someone has done this already.

Answer (score 1):

That `RA` tool does not have an option to output the SQL queries.

However, the mapping from relational algebra to SQL is pretty much trivial (except for division), can be easily found with a web search, and is something you should have learned in your course.

If you want to find out how `RA` handles this, look into the file `RAXNode.java`.
The various classes derived from `RAXNode` each implement one relational algebra operation; the method `toPrintString` shows the RA operation, while `genViewDef` generates the corresponding SQL command.
For example:

```java
public static class PROJECT extends RAXNode {
    public String toPrintString() {
        return "\\project_{" + _columns + "}";
    }
    public String genViewDef(DB db) {
        return "SELECT DISTINCT " + _columns + " FROM " + getChild(0).getViewName();
    }
}
...
public static class INTERSECT extends RAXNode {
    public String toPrintString() {
        return "\\intersect";
    }
    public String genViewDef(DB db) {
        if (db.getDriverName().equals("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")) {
            // MySQL doesn't support INTERSECT, so we need a workaround.
            ...
        } else {
            return "SELECT * FROM " + getChild(0).getViewName() +
                " INTERSECT SELECT * FROM " + getChild(1).getViewName();
        }
    }
}
```